# How to have a responsive hero background image with VH?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background, background-image

:)

I have a responsive header.

Here's the code for the hero section:

```
.hero {
    background: url(../../img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    @include breakpoint($x-large) {
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
```

It's all great and responsive; however, when I open the console on web or keyboard on android the vh doesn't change and the button and text elements stay shifted down.

I've tried adding padding and specific media queries and other solutions, but I cannot find a universal effective solution...

**Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach `.container-hero` to the bottom of the `.hero`.

```
.container-hero {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
}
```

You'll also need to fix your layout due to `position: absolute;`.

But you get the idea :)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<style>
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwAUR.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
```

Comment: When you resize the window the image is skewed.